# Why does iOS show me a "home" location when I'm abroad without data roaming?

Tags: ios, iphone, location, core-location

I'm working on an iOS app which uses `Core Location`.

I'm usually based in the UK but have been in the US for the past week. When the app can't get a location fix, or doesn't have data service (I've turned roaming data off) it confidently reports its location as Piccadilly Square in London, but when I'm connected to a known WiFi point it corrects itself to the other side of the Atlantic.

Why is this, and how can I check for erroneous location information (e.g. confident reports of being in London) and filter them out?

Comment: Are you checking the timestamp property of the CLLocation object? Sometimes an old location can be reported via the CLLocationManagerDelegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your scheme settings… do you have Default Location set under Run -> Options?

[image]

This value seems to persist even when the app isn't running, but restarting your phone fixes the issue.

Comment: This sounds like it might work -- trying it out now.

Comment: Thanks! This worked eventually, although the location simulation setting is oddly persistent -- it took a change in default location, two reboots and two rebuilds to get it to turn off completely.